# Kendo grid icon column shows ellipsis in chrome Version :58.0.3029.96

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-grid

When loads the grid decreasing size of icon columns, so ellipsis appears instead of icon.  When we expand the column then it shows the icon.

I assigned a width to kendo grid coloumns, which has icons.
"#mygrid" has column array with 2 fields, icons and assigned width:"20px"
which is visible in older version of chrome but not in latest version which is Version :58.0.3029.96 [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ExIxe/2)

```
    $("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: acc,
        columns:[
            {
                field: "abc",
                title: " ", 
                width : "20px",
                template: 
                 '<a onclick=" " title="abc" href="Javascript:void(0);">
                   <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                 </a>'  
            },
            {
                field: "xyz",
                title: " ", 
                width : "20px",
                template: 
                 '<a onclick=" " title="abc" href="Javascript:void(0);">
                   <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                 </a>'  
            }],
        groupable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filterable: true
     });
```

Comment: what is the display value for that link ? if inline, then no size can be specified.

Comment: I think it's the default behavior for resizable columns

Comment: Your issue might be with the default padding applied by Kendo, have you tried removing that to see if the FA icon is visible then? Can you make an example at dojo.telerik.com to show the issue?

Comment: it display icon in older version of chrome which has width : "20px". if I removed the width hides the whole column

Comment: @Dryden Long: added dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/ExIxe/2

Comment: @GCyrillus: can see value for that link in dojo, tried with no size but hiding columns. now using kendo version v2013.3.1119.  Some times it shows ellipsis otherwise shows half icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo automatically applies `padding` to the table cells, which is causing your anchor links/fa icons to be shifted out of view. In order to fix this, you'll want to add a class to the `td` elements containing the fa icons and manually overwrite their padding like so:

```
    columns:[
        {
            field: "",
            title: " ",
            width: "20px",
            //Here is where we assign the class. 
            //Do this for each column containing a font awesome icon
            attributes: {
                "class": "faContainer"
            },
            template:
             '<a title="abc"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></a>'
        }
    ]
```

Then your CSS would include something like this:

```
.k-grid .faContainer {
  padding: 0px;
}  
.faContainer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a Dojo link showing it off: http://dojo.telerik.com/evoGA

Comment: It works!! thanks a lot :), I think it would work if chrome will update to next version.